# Using Kolmogorov's 0-1 law in proof of shift map being ergodic

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, transformation, ergodic-theory

[image]

Why should ${\cal E}_\theta$ be trivial?. I dont see how Kolmogorov's 0-1 law says that in this case we should take the 0 option.

This is only mention of ${\cal E}_\theta$ in my notes I can find.

[image]

Comment: What is $\xi_\theta$? I don't see a definition for it in the theorem, or even mentioned.

Comment: @AdamHughes Only mention I can find is in the edit

Comment: You are writing $\xi_\theta$ where the book writes ${\cal E}_\theta$. This completely different notation is what's confusing us....

Comment: "A set $A\in{\cal E}$ is called invariant if $A=\theta^{-1}(A)$. The class of all invariant sets forms a $\sigma$-algebra, which we denote by ${\cal E}_\theta$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sigma-algebra is *trivial* when it contains only sets of measure $0$ or $1$. There is no "0 option" here, that "we should take".